# How can I programmatically install a plugin?

Tags: plugin, joomla3.8

How could you do programmatically what Joomla does when you install a plugin? Let's say, for simplicity's sake, that you have a plugin package file local with your Joomla instance.

A solution might look like one of:

- a) You make a POST request to a Joomla endpoint with the package file that installs the plugin.
- b) You write a shell script that both installs the package file's contents in the correct folder, and writes the required data to the db (more brittle this way).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Install model.

```
if (!defined('_JEXEC'))
{
    define('_JEXEC', 1);
    define('JPATH_BASE', realpath(__DIR__));
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php';
    require_once JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php';
}

JModelLegacy::addIncludePath(JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR . '/components/com_installer/models', 'InstallerModel');
$input = JFactory::getApplication('site')->input;
$input->set('installtype', 'folder');
$input->set('install_directory', $path);
$model = JModelLegacy::getInstance('Install', 'InstallerModel', array('ignore_request' => true));
$model->install();
```

Where `$path` is path to extension installation files.

Comment: Thanks for this. This would work once I have access to the Joomla runtime. Do you know of any way this could be done externally, without access to that runtime?

Comment: If you need to run this in external script, add Joomla dependencies and define the application in `JFactory::getApplication()` call. I have updated the answer to reflect this. You may also look into making a CLI application.

Comment: You can create a new controller inside your component, and call it externally via GET/POST and pass the required details as paramteres.