# Install extension from external script

Tags: external-script

Hi I'm automating the Joomla Installations, I'm looking for a way to install an extension from an external script.

I've found [this solution](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23220/how-can-i-programmatically-install-a-plugin), but there is an issue, and that is, the "external script" also is a Joomla! install, and now, when I think of the solution, the constants will collide. Any way to get this working?

Comment: Are you aware of how to set up a Joomla CLI application - ie one you can just run as a PHP script on the server from cron? I would have thought that that would be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

One solution that comes to mind is, just get a simple php file with the ["installation script"](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/23220/how-can-i-programmatically-install-a-plugin) dropped in the target Joomla instance root, and then hit that script via CURL, that way the instances/runtimes are untangled and after the installation is completed, delete the "installation script".